# Onsite Recurring Payments using Paypal Website Payments Pro API

Tags: api, paypal, payment, recurring

I want to accept recurring payments on my site using paypal without having the user ever leave my site.  Based on the paypal documentation it appears you have to send the user offsite to paypal (express checkout) first and then have them come back to your site.

Is their a different way of using the api so the user stays on site the entire time?

Answer (score 1):

To Process payments not on PayPal's website, you need to use Website Payments Pro.

### To use PayPal's recurring payment system, without programming your own:

- [Use Website Payments Pro Recurring Payments (direct payment recurring payments / DPRP)](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments)

### Program your own recurring payment functionality:

- Save cc info to a database and [make DoDirectPayment API calls](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPDirectPayment) based on your criteria
- Process an initial payment when someone signs up for your recurring service, save the transaction ID, and then [call DoReferenceTransaction](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoReferenceTransaction) in the future (based on your criteria). Always use the newest transaction ID as they only last a year. Also, you need to call PayPal to apply for this feature ($0).